# PostGIS: Precision of functions

Tags: postgresql, rounding, postgis

Why can results of idential queries on two Postgres/PostGIS-installations differ?

I have two Linux VM (Centos 9, Postgres 12.8; Kubuntu 20.04, postgres 12.9) in a common host (VMWare on Windows) each running Postgres with PostGIS extension.
Running a regression test with idential testdata on both gives different results:
ST_AsText rounds differently, unless I restrict precision (e.g. ST_AsText(_ , 13) instead of the default ST_AsText(_ , 15).

I understand that a precision of 13 decimals is by far enough. Nevertheless I would like to understand what characteristic of the installation can result in the difference observed.

```
CentOS:
psql (12.4, server 12.8)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=> select p, ST_AsText(p, 15)  from (select ST_PointN(path_geogr::geometry, 18) as p from track where id=4) as _;
                         p                          |                st_astext
----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000000080C731971C400000B8488E754940 | POINT(7.14765083044767 50.9184046648443)
(1 row)

Kubuntu:
psql (12.4, server 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-2.pgdg20.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=> select p, ST_AsText(p, 15)  from (select ST_PointN(path_geogr::geometry, 18) as p from track where id=4) as _;
                         p                          |                  st_astext
----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000000080C731971C400000B8488E754940 | POINT(7.147650830447674 50.918404664844275)
(1 row)
```

Comment: as noted above: on kubuntu runs postgres 12.9, on centos 12.8

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS uses `double precision` to represent coordinates. If the computation differs slightly (for example, different execution plans), the result can differ slightly.

Comment: I understand that an "execution plan" describes the way the RDBMS collects the information requestesd by a query (typically when more than one table is involved, e.g. which index is used), so it is the kind of information given by EXPLAIN / ALANYZE. How can this influence rounding of numeric calculations?

Comment: Well, it makes a difference in which order you add up numbers, for example.